# calling function with xslt using xpath selection

Tags: xslt, msxsl

How can I call javascript/c# function in xslt passing xpath selection value.
Here is how I call function with manualy typed parameter:

```
<xsl:value-of select="cs:my('some text')"/>
```

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use? With C# it could be System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform, it is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxaw5z5e.aspx. Basically an XSLT/XPath node-set is received by your C# function as an XPathNodeIterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is an example from the [MSXML 4 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=19662)** (this should be the same for MSXML 6, and is quite similar for .NEt's XslCompiledTransform -- for the latter **[search MSDN for `<msxsl:script>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256042.aspx)**)

> **Example** This example defines a script block with a namespace
>   prefix of user that contains a function called xml that takes a
>   node-list as an argument. Later, this function, xml(nodelist) in the
>   user namespace, is called from the select attribute of .
>
> **XML File (customers.xml)**
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="script.xsl" ?>
> <customers>
>    <customer>
>       <name>John Smith</name>
>       <address>123 Elm St.</address>
>       <phone>(123) 456-7890</phone>
>    </customer>
>    <customer>
>       <name>Mary Jones</name>
>       <address>456 Oak Ave.</address>
>       <phone>(156) 789-0123</phone>
>    </customer>
> </customers>
> ```
>
> **XSLT File (script.xsl)**
>
> ```
> <?xml version='1.0'?>
> <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
>       xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>       xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
>       xmlns:user="http://mycompany.com/mynamespace">
>
> <msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="user">
>    function xml(nodelist) {
>       return nodelist.nextNode().xml;
>    }
> </msxsl:script>
>
> <xsl:template match="/">
>    <xsl:value-of select="user:xml(.)"/>
> </xsl:template>
>
> </xsl:stylesheet>
> ```
>
> **Formatted Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>&lt;?xml version="1.0"?&gt;
&lt;?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="script.xsl" ?&gt;
&lt;customers&gt;
 &lt;customer&gt;
  &lt;name&gt;John Smith&lt;/name&gt;
  &lt;address&gt;123 Elm St.&lt;/address&gt;
  &lt;phone&gt;(123) 456-7890&lt;/phone&gt;
 &lt;/customer&gt;
 &lt;customer&gt;
  &lt;name&gt;Mary Jones&lt;/name&gt;
  &lt;address&gt;456 Oak Ave.&lt;/address&gt;
  &lt;phone&gt;(156) 789-0123&lt;/phone&gt;
 &lt;/customer&gt;
&lt;/customers&gt;
```